# Issue in react App.tsx file using Vite frontend tool

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite

I have created sample react app using vite frontend tool, but getting an errors in App.tsx file without modifying file.

[image: App.tsx file]

[image: .eslintrc file]

How to resolve this issue?

I have already updated vscode(1.85)

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Memory: 5.87 GB / 15.92 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.10.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE     
    Yarn: 1.22.21 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD       
    npm: 10.2.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD        
  Browsers:
    Edge: Chromium (120.0.2210.91)
    Internet Explorer: 11.0.19041.3636
  npmPackages:
    @vitejs/plugin-react: ^4.2.1 => 4.2.1 
    vite: ^5.0.8 => 5.0.10
```

Comment: install typescript

Comment: npm update typescript -g

Comment: Do not post pictures of text when you can post the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue and this issue is in the VS Code settings.

Removed below settings :

"files.associations": {
"*.tsx": "typescript"
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).